# why need Hidden Layer in Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I am new to learn Neural Network at Machine Learning. when i calculate activation functions for boolean functions like AND/OR/NOT, there need not `Hidden Layer` but XOR/XNOR and so on  boolean function need  `Hidden Layer` for calculating activation function. why? (I search in google for that but can't take clear knowledge for that). Are there `number of neuron` in Hidden layer dependent at number of Input neuron??

Comment: What kind of activation function do you use? Step function or in other words your neuronal network are perceptrons? Then the reason is that one layer only gives you hyperplanes that seperates your space in two halfs. Now see how xor looks geometric: http://www.byclb.com/TR/Tutorials/neural_networks/ch8_1_dosyalar/image071.jpg You cannot linearly seperate the '1' from the '0', but you need a way to intersect the hyperplanes (and that can be done by an additional hidden layer).

Comment: Sigmoid function @uberwach

Comment: You can follow [hidden-layer-in-a-neural-network-compute][1]. I think it will be helpful for you


  [1]: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63152/what-does-the-hidden-layer-in-a-neural-network-compute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If to put simply hidden layer adds additional transformation of inputs, which is not easy achievable with single layer networks ( one of the ways to achieve it is to add some kind of non linearity to your input). Second layer adds additional transformations and can feet to more complicated tasks. If to speak about AND/OR/NOT they are considered as linearly separable tasks. 
  [image: And graphical representation]
Look at picture which displays values of AND ( three dots are for false). It's possible to separate true values from false values with one line, and this can be done with help of neural network without hidden layers. But if to speak about XOR/XNOR you need two lines, and two lines can be constructed by neural network with two layers and with non linear activation function. Yellow line shows separation which can be done with neural network.

Comment: Are there number of neuron in Hidden layer dependent at number of Input neuron??

Comment: There is general recommendation to make number at hidden layer as 2/3 of input layer. But it is not written in stone, other parameters also can work

Answer (score 0):

To put it even more simply: If your outputs are non-linear (XOR) for example, you need a hidden layer. But if you do add one, you're pretty much committed to a non-linear output function (Sigmoid) and will need to incorporate back propagation into your algorithm. The hidden layer weights are primarily adjusted by the back-prop routine and that's where the network gains the ability to solve for non-linearity. A thought example describing non-linearity: You have a volume control knob, marked off 1 to 10. The higher the number, the louder the sound. But if we had a control that increased the volume from 1 to 5 and then started decreasing the volume from 6 to 10, that would be a non-linear function that a non-linear Neural net could solve.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if we have more hidden layer then we will get good predicted values and best accuracy  for the dataset . So every node in the hidden layer will take one or more features from the dataset and  it is going to apply the weights and activation function until we get the good predicted values. And it uses the backward propagation for updating the weights .

Backward propagation means  here is to minimise the cost function and to get as soon as you found a minute of the cost function that is your final neural network that means your weights have been adjusted and you have found the optimal weights for this dataset that you began your training on and you're ready to proceed to the testing phase or to the application phase.